# The region of Viceroy Toledo's Reductions (Reducciones)?

Tags: colonization, south-america

I'm trying to find the geographic boundaries for the native resettlement implemented by Toledo, Viceroy of Peru, as a part of his Toledo reforms. This resettlement is distinct from the later Jesuit reductions. However, I can't find any information on the geographic boundaries. Or more detailed information about the specifics of this reform.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were no actual "boundaries" as far as I had been able to research; the Spaniards relocated the natives, not into a closed area but scattering them in some 600 reducciones all around the Viceroyalty, and most of the time the natives appear to have been resettled not excessively far from their original villages, while local chiefs appear to have had a say on the placement of the *reducciones*. You might want to look at Jeremy Ravi Mumford's *Vertical Empires: The General Resettlement of Indians in the Colonial Andes*, which appears to be a fine book on the subject — chapter 8 mentions the topic of the placement of the *reducciones*, and you can see some pages of it in [Google Books](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=AbJcJQg3x7EC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA119#v=onepage&q&f=false). In [this other text](http://www.yale.edu/macmillan/lais/rethinkingSpace/Mumford-Forced%20Resettlement.pdf), the author makes a general outline of the thesis he puts forward in the book.